# is it possible to leave the Silent Realm without completing the trial?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

After entering the Silent Realm for another trial I seem to fail miserably.

Is it possible to leave the Silent Realm so I can do something else for a while, or do I have to complete the trial to be able to leave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you leave the starting circle, you can reenter it which will also make the timer pause. The center of the starting circle can be examined by pressing the A button, this will give you an option to leave.